# Why app delegate class cannot be initialized?

Tags: ios, oop, object, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

why we dont alloc and init appdelegate class just like we initialize all other view controller classes?
I am a beginner in ios programming .please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't allocate our app delegates because the system does it for us. Please take a look at the `main.m` class from your Xcode project:

```
//
//  main.m
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you alloc and initialize any delegate class  the variables will be null and you cannot use the method . If you want to use any variable or method from delegate class try something like this

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString * deviceToken=appDelegate.deviceToken;
```

I hope you got your answer.

Comment: but why variables would be null ? that is my question.